# Is there a more efficient idiom for working with EntityManagers?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, jpa-2.0

#### All the documentation I can find shows this idiom as required for every access:

```
final EntityManager em = EMF.TRANSACTIONS_OPTIONAL.createEntityManager();
try
{    
    // do query and return result here
    return q.getSingleResult();
}
finally
{
    em.close();
}
```

This causes problems when I try and use one method that looks up all a list of Objects and then another method uses that list to update/delete the Objects I get errors about the objects being `detached`?

Is there a more efficient way to wrap up the logic from the boilerplate that I am not finding?

Answer (score 2):

Creating (emf.createEntityManager() ) and closing entityManager (em.close() ) is indeed a boilerplate that you should delegate to some framework.

For JEE apps, you can achieve this with annotations @PersistenceContext and @TransactionAttribute:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "my-unit")
private EntityManager entityManager;

@TransactionAttribute
public void myMethod(Item item) {
    // do em.find(), em.createQuery(), query.getResultList(), etc.
    // no need to init em nor close it
}
```

Spring does this easily in both JEE and non-JEE apps with its @Transactional annotation and a few lines of xml config.

However, whichever approach you use, once em is closed (by you calling em.close() or by a framework doing its work based on some config/annotations) you will get detached objects.

In order to work with detached objects in some em methods (like deleting with em.remove()), you need to 'merge' them back into the context:

```
em.merge(myDetachedObject);
em.remove(myDetachedObject); // now it's attached so it can be removed
```

Updating a detached object is easy, because simple em.merge() does this already (besides merging the object to the context).